# Installing in cmd vs installing in Jupyter notebook

Tags: installation, fastapi

I want to install Fast API in system and I was wondering whether installing it in jupyter notebook is same as installing it in CMD. After reading online I could not come to a conclusion. Therefore, I wanted to know what should be a preferred way to get on with installation in  any case.

This is just a general query

Answer (score 0):

Installing FastAPI is generally the same whether you do it in Jupyter Notebook or the command prompt (CMD). You can use Python's package manager, pip, to install FastAPI in both environments.

To install FastAPI in CMD, open your command prompt or terminal and run:

```
pip install fastapi
```

To install FastAPI in a Jupyter Notebook, you can use a Jupyter Notebook cell and run the following command:

```
!pip install fastapi
```

Both methods achieve the same result, which is to install FastAPI in your Python environment.

After installation, you can import FastAPI and start building web applications and APIs using FastAPI in both environments.

Comment: Does FastAPI not use a modern version of Jupyter? With a modern version of Jupyter, the recommendation with be `%pip install fastapi`. You'll have a much better experience in **mordern** Jupyter on more systems using the current best practice of using the modern magic install commands that insure the installations occur in the environment where the kernel is running, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for more about those commands. The exclamation point doesn't insure the correct environment always.